# AngularJS no longer responds after inital start-up in Spring-Boot

Tags: angularjs, spring, spring-boot

My application loads all the scripts and pictures for the home page. However I get a 404 error for the slider images and all the buttons do not work.

Slider:

[image]

I confirmed my AngularJS controllers are working by printing out the following in the console:

[image]

For some reason it seems once the application is compiled all external links are irrelevant.

Directory:

[image]

My index.html file loads the scripts and the initial view via `<ng-view>`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="SharpVision">
    <head>
        <base href="/">
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1" />  
        <title>My Page</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
        <meta name="My Page personal site" content="Personal" />
        <meta name="author" content="AHthemes" />

        <!-- HTML5 Shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
        <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
        <!--[if lt IE 9]>
          <!--<script src="http://a1alfred.com/sharpvisionbs3/v2/angular/assets/libs/html5shiv/html5shiv.min.js"></script>-->
          <!--<script src="http://a1alfred.com/sharpvisionbs3/v2/angular/assets/libs/respond/respond.min.js"></script>-->
        <![endif]-->
        <!--[if gte IE 9]>
          <style type="text/css">
            .gradient {
               filter: none;
            }

          </style>
        <![endif]-->

        <link href="assets/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="assets/css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>
    <body>

        <ng-include src="'app/views/structure/navigation.tpl.html'"></ng-include>

        <ng-view autoscroll="true"></ng-view>

        <ng-include src="'app/views/structure/footer.tpl.html'"></ng-include >

        <!--Scripts-->
        <!--<script src="bower_components/masonry/dist/masonry.pkgd.min.js"></script>-->
        <!--<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>-->
        <script src="assets/libs/flexslider/jquery.flexslider.js"></script>
        <script src="assets/libs/masonry/masonry.pkgd.min.js"></script>
        <script src="assets/libs/imagesloaded/imagesloaded.pkgd.min.js"></script>
        <script src="assets/libs/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script src="assets/libs/angular/angular-route.min.js"></script>
        <script src="assets/libs/angular/angular-sanitize.min.js"></script>
        <script src="assets/libs/angular/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.13.0.min.js"></script>
        <script src="assets/libs/angular-flexslider/angular-flexslider.js"></script>
        <script src="assets/libs/angular-backstretch/ng-backstretch.min.js"></script>
        <script src="assets/libs/angular-parallax/angular-parallax.js"></script>
        <script src="assets/libs/angular-fitvids/angular-fitvids.js"></script>
        <script src="assets/libs/angular-masonry/angular-masonry.min.js"></script>
        <script src="assets/libs/momentjs/moment-with-locales.min.js"></script>
        <script src="assets/libs/humanize-duration/humanize-duration.js"></script>
        <script src="assets/libs/angular-timer/angular-timer.min.js"></script>
        <script src="assets/libs/ng-progress/js/ngprogress.min.js"></script>
        <script src="assets/libs/angular-gmaps/angular-google-maps.min.js"></script>
        <script src="assets/libs/lodash/lodash.min.js"></script>
        <script src='//maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false'></script>
        <script src="app/app.module.js"></script>
        <script src="app/app.directives.js"></script>
        <script src="app/app.routes.js"></script>
        <script src="app/app.controllers.js"></script>

    </body>
</html>
```

then my route are configured like such:

```
app.config(function($routeProvider, $locationProvider){
    $routeProvider.when('/',{
        templateUrl: "app/views/misc/home.tpl.html",
        controller: "HomeController"
    })
```

Goes to my HomeController:

```
  app.controller('HomeController', function($scope, ROOT) {
        $scope.Root = ROOT;
        console.log("In Home Controller")
        $scope.top = {

            backstretch: [
                ROOT+'/assets/img/big/big-1.jpg',
                ROOT+'/assets/img/big/big-2.jpg',
                ROOT+'/assets/img/big/big-4.jpg'
            ]
        };
    });

Get the name ROOT injected from the module:

     app.constant('ROOT', '/PersonalSite/src/main/resources/static');
```

In my NavigationController:

```
app.controller('NavigationController', function($scope, ROOT, ngProgressFactory, $window) {
    $scope.Root = ROOT;
    $scope.brand = 'Drew';
    $scope.isCollapsed = true;
    $scope.progressbar = ngProgressFactory.createInstance();
    $scope.progressbar.setColor('#02bbff');
    $scope.progressbar.start();
    $scope.$on('$routeChangeStart', function(next, current) { 
        $scope.isCollapsed = true;
        $scope.progressbar.start();
    });
    console.log("In NavigationController");
    $scope.menu = {
        items: [
            {
                link: ROOT+"/",
                name: "Home"
            },
            {
                link: ROOT+"/features/portfolioitem",
                name: "Gallery"
            }, 
{
                link: ROOT+"/contact",
                name: "Contact"
            }

        ]
    };
```

What is confusing when I click on a button `href` I get `In HomeController` in the console. Therefore it is responsive but still not working. I had the application working until I brought in Spring-Boot, now just index.html loads.

```
  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ylsZm.png
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/LMJSt.png
  [3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/91n7A.png
```

Comment: Why do you have the path "src/main/resources/static" in your JavaScript file? Spring Boot maps the content in the static folder to the context root, so just remove "src/main/resources/static" and it should work.

Comment: Thank you, that solved it!!!